# Beancreationexception+NosuchBeandefinition exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-4

I am working on Spring 4 application with SpringBoot.

In com.test.tm  package,
Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication   
@EnableJpaRepositories( repositoryFactoryBeanClass = GenericRepositoryFactoryBean.class )  
@Import( { HikariDataSourceConfig.class } )  
public class Application {  
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }  
}
```

In com.test.tm.entities package,
User Class:

```
@Table( name = "test.user" )
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
  private Integer id;
  private String message;  
  ....  
}
```

In com.test.tm.user
UserService.class:

```
@Service
@Transactional( rollbackFor = Exception.class )
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private GenericRepository<User, Serializable> gr;

 public User saveEntity( User usr )
 {
    return gr.save(usr);
 }

 public String getUser()
 {
    //Get User logic
 }  
}
```

GenericRepository.java:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {
    public List<T> findByNamedQuery( String name );
    public List<T> findByNamedQueryAndParams( String name, Map<String, Object> params );
 }
```

There is a `GenericRepositoryImpl.java` as well where logic for above methods are implemented.

On running Application.java, I am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.test.utils.spring.repo.GenericRepository com.test.tm.user.UserService.gr; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type[com.test.utils.spring.repo.GenericRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.Dependency annotations: {@ org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required = true) }
```

1. There is no such variable called userService which I defined, but still it shows error.
2. Any way I can fix the above issue.

Comment: For 1/ SpringBoot will automatically scan the current package (default) where Application.java is located and resolved the autowired field (like gr).

Comment: For 2/ I don't know what com.test.utils.spring.repo.GenericRepository is, can you add it to your post?

Comment: @alias_boubou: I have added GenricRepository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad. 1.
Spring creates `userService` bean with default name, as indicated in [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-beanname).

Ad. 2. I'm not sue, sure, but perhaps `GenericRepositoryImpl` is outside of 
`com.test.tm` package? If yes, then specify additional `@ComponentScan` annotation with proper package declaration ie.`@ComponentScan("com.test.utils")`, or - if You use Boot 1.3+ - modify `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.test.utils","com.test.tm"})`